# How do I get a view from other activity?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

Let's say I have two activities/classes. **MainActivity** and **SecondActivity**. For each of these activities I have individual XML files. In **SecondActivity**, I have a `ListView` with ID `listview`.

How can I retreive the `ListView` from **SecondActivity** in **MainActivity**?

I tried just plain and simple (in MainActivity.java):

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

But that crashes my app when I try to set an adapter on it (nullPointerException). I tried placing it directly inside my class, and inside the onCreate method. Both causes a crash.

The line that causes the crash looks like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
listview.setAdapter(adapter); //crash (nullpointerexception pointing to nullobject)
```

What I want to do is get that ListView and use the "listview" object to add elements to the listview in my MainActivity.

Comment: "How can I retreive the ListView from SecondActivity in MainActivity?" -- you don't, just as one Web page does not access the DOM of another Web page. If these bits of UI are that tightly coupled, make them be fragments with a shared `ViewModel`.

Comment: Activities are process entry points with an associated window, and not just "screens" or "ui elements" or "views". You can start the app in such a way that `SecondActivity` exists, but `MainActivity` has never existed during this session / in this process. You should not rely on such a connection between the two.

Comment: Do you have a custom adapter for your list view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android (with exceptions) you cannot have more than one activity running at the same time. You can have multiple Fragments, but a single activity is shown at a single time (ok, this is not 100% true anymore, but for all intents and purposes, this is still the case).

What you're trying to do is considered extremely bad practice in Android (and iOS for what is worth).

#### What can/should you do?

Your requirements appear to be some form of: I have a list of items, and I also have another activity where I want to add or remove things from said list.

This is fine, but you don't need "two activities" to do this.

Have one activity to show the list, and when you want to add the contents, either launch another activity to show the UI of the "edit/add" or use Fragments (one Fragment would have the list, the other would have the UI to edit the list).

Where is the data in all this?

Stored in a THIRD place (let's call it "YourListRepository"), which is a class where:

1. From the "List" you'd simply say: Repository, give me the latest list!
2. From the "Edit" screen, you'd say: Repository, give me the item "N" from the list. And then, you'd say: Repository, here's the updated item "N", refresh it.

Going back to 1 (to display the updated list) is automatic, since it asks "for the latest list".

#### Where to learn more?

Given the tenure of the question you posted, it appears that you're relatively new to Android development, and therefore I suggest you spend an hour of your time, reading [Application Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals) from the official Google documentation.